# How do I integrate my payment source app with existing electronic wallets

Tags: android, ios, wallet

I have been tasked to develop a prototype for a new pay system in android/iOS app form.

The app will replace mag stripe cards and receive the card and client data directly from the issuer.

The app will also allow pos and atm transactions directly from the smart device.

Existing wallets (Google pay, Apple Pay) offer the POS/ATM interface, but my question is how do I install my pay app as a service in these wallets? So that a consumer who has had their card issued through my app, can install and use my app as a payment source.

I hope my question is clear. Please ask any questions you may have.

Thanks for any direction.

Comment: Apple Pay integration requires the card issuer to work with Apple directly. Apps cannot add payment methods to the iOS wallet

Comment: Thanks! Your clarification helped me shortcut a lot of work. :-)